# ¿Como crear un modelo de una base de datos existente? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buenas, mi duda es la siguiente,

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en rails, pero ya tengo las bases de datos creadas, una de las tablas por ejemplo se llama "UsersMaster" y no puedo modificar su nombre.

¿Ahora bien, como creo un modelo en rails para esa tabla para poder usar el ActiveRecord?

Comment: necesitas hacer solo el modelo o tambien el controlador, tests y otros?

Answer (score 1):

Creo que para este tipo de tareas siempre es mejor crear los modelos a mano, algo como:

```
class NuevoModelo < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "nombreDeTablaRaro"
  set_primary_key "IDQueNoSigueConvencionRails"
end
```

Pero si no quieres darte el trabajo, podrías probar a usar [rmre](https://github.com/bosko/rmre) que usa ingeniería inversa para generan los modelos. Lleva ya un tiempo sin mantención, pero tampoco ha cambiado mucho la estructura básica de un modelo rails 3 a lo que es hoy rails 5.

Luego de instalar la gema con `gem install rmre`, comienzas el proceso con

```
rmre -a mysql2 -d basededatos -u usuario -p contraseña -o /ruta/donde/crear/modelos`
```

Obviamente `mysql2` lo puedes cambiar por el adaptador que estés usando para tu motor específico.
De todas formas no te fies al 100% de lo que te genere y adaptalo a tus propias necesidades o convenciones de nombres que quieras usar para tus modelos.